# UIImage size depending on UITableViewCell height

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I have a UITableView whose cells have dynamic height. What I want to do is basically having an image that works as container for each tableview row like in the following picture. Since the content for each row is different, the image should be resized in height to contain the text of the cell.

[image: Image container for cell]

I am wondering what is the best practice to achieve it.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a background image view for the cell and set the frame size based on the content you have to place inside the cell. Then you can use the "stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:topCapHeight:" method to create the image that you want to set the cell background.

```
 UIImage *backgroundImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:30  topCapHeight:20];

[cell.bgImageView setFrame:CGRectMake(a, b, c, d];
cell.bgImageView.image = backgroundImg;
```

Comment: The method is deprecated in iOS 5 so you I had to use **resizableImageWithCapInsets:(UIEdgeInsets)capInsets** The problem is  that the image is repeated and not stretched.

Comment: Here follows my code: `UIEdgeInsets insets;
            insets.top = 20;
            insets.left = 0;
            insets.bottom = 20;
            insets.right = 0;
UIImage *backgroundImg = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"container.png"] resizableImageWithCapInsets:insets];
cell.frame = CGRectMake(cell.frame.origin.x, cell.frame.origin.x, CELL_CONTENT_WIDTH, MAX(size.height, 70.0f));
UIView* backgroundView = [[ UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
            cell.backgroundView = backgroundView;
backgroundView.backgroundColor = [ UIColor colorWithPatternImage:backgroundImg];`

Comment: Use UIimageView instead of the UIView for the background view and set the "backgroundImg" to UIImage view without setting the color.

Answer (score 0):

Yo can use method sizeToFit for this image. else use the image type as center or scaleToFit.